# Помогите написать JMS заглушку в NETBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jms

Необходимо написать JMS заглушку в NetBeans.
Задание:
Во внешнюю систему, очередь ToOtherBank
JMSCorrelationID запроса и ответ должен совпадать

```
<accountTransferRq>
    <fromAcc>11111111111111111111</fromAcc>
    <sum>100.0</sum>
    <toAcc>22222222222222222222</toAcc>
</accountTransferRq>
```

Ответ в очередь FromOtherBank

```
<accountTransferRs>
    <description>Description</description>
    <statusCode>1</statusCode>
</accountTransferRs>
```

Что уже есть:

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    static Connection connection;
    static Session session;
    private static void init() {
        try {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory("******");
            connection = factory.createConnection("admin","");
            session = connection.createSession();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error create connection");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
        sendMessage("input", "testText OK", "123");
        String textMessage = getMessage("input", "123");
        System.out.println("receive text = "+textMessage);
        if(textMessage.contains("OK")){
            
        }else{
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void sendMessage(String queue,String msgText,String correlationID) {
        try {
            TextMessage tmsg = session.createTextMessage(msgText);
            tmsg.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationID);
            Queue queueInput = session.createQueue(queue);
            MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(null);
            mp.send(queueInput, tmsg);
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error create message");
        }
    }
    
    public static String getMessage(String queue,String correlationId) {
        try {
            Queue queueOutput = session.createQueue(queue);
            String query = "JMSCorrelationID ='"+correlationId+"'";
            MessageConsumer mc = session.createConsumer(queueOutput, query);
            connection.start();
            TextMessage tmsg = (TextMessage) mc.receive(10000);
            mc.close();
            connection.stop();
            return tmsg.getText();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error getMessage");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: не до конца понимаю, что нужно еще по заданию дописать, чтобы код был корректный